# UL not displaying in IE8 Compatability Mode

Tags: html, html-lists, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a basic  unordered list that isn't displaying in IE8 compatibility mode, but when compatibility mode is turned off it displays correctly.

I discovered the problem. It turned out to be that it doesn't like the background:none property on a list item.

Comment: Please elaborate. Add some code or give us a url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turns out to be a problem with background:none on a list item.  I was doing custom bullets by setting the background image, and on the first item i was just setting it to background none, but this caused the whole list to disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code in IE8(compatible mode turned off)
It works !!

```
<html>
<body>
<ul type="disc">
<li>hii</li>
<li>bye</li>
<li>hello</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```